# RVM is not being used by Ubuntu Launcher

Tags: ruby, bash, ubuntu, rvm, environment-variables

I'm trying to make my data files "clickable" like a MS Word document.  When a user clicks on a file on the desktop with a ".vr" extension, I want it to execute my Ruby script, and pass the file name as a parameter.

I've created a mime type, "text/vr" with the ".vr" extension, and when I click the file, "text.vr" on the desktop, it attempts to run the command:

```
$vr test.vr
```

This command fails because it tries to use an old version of Ruby.  The problem is that Ubuntu uses a different environment when it launches a program from the desktop instead of the prompt.

I use RVM, and it works perfectly when I write programs in the terminal.  However, when I click on the file to launch the vr script, RVM isn't used.  I need to find a way to make RVM load when a file is clicked.

What's going on here?  What environment file is loaded when you execute a file from the desktop? ~/.bashrc?  ~/.profile?   How can I make it so my whole computer always finds RVM?

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few ways, the environment for desktop is loaded from `.profile`, add one of this:

```
source $HOME/.rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.3-p327 #OR:
source $HOME/.rvm/environments/default
```

to load specific ruby.

sometimes it might not work with sourcing, then adding content of the default file to `.profile` should work:

```
cat $HOME/.rvm/environments/default >> ~/.profile
```

It is required to relogin / restart to apply the changes.

Comment: Thank You!!  I've verified that rvm is now being used, but I have a new problem:  Somehow its using the wrong rubygems folder.  Now when I run my ruby script, the errors refer to this folder:  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/   This is incorrect.  RVM is set to use 1.9.3, and I've made it output the command "ruby -v" which verifies that 1.9.3 is being used.  Also I've had it output the command:  "gem environment"  which shows everything is set to 1.9.3 as well?!?!?  So its using 1.9.3, but looking for gems in an old gem folder.  Any ideas?  Typo in your PATH:  "/rvm" should be "/.rvm"

Comment: Thanks mpapis.  I got it to work.  Your solution above is correct.  However, I couldn't get the "source" command to work.  I had to cut and paste the contents of the "default" file into my ~/.profile file to get it to work.  Keep up the good work!!  Typo: should be $HOME/.rvm/envir....

Comment: I got it to work by adding this line:  . ~/.rvm/environments/default